# Uploading multiple files without any gems by passing param array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that I can add multiple images to.

```
<%= form_with(model: photo, remote: true, multipart: true) do |form| %>
    <input type="file" name="images" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple>

    <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to pass the multiple images to my controller method through params. Once uploaded to the method through the params I want to cycle through and create a link like this.

```
  def create
      Rails.logger.debug "#{params[:images]}"
      params[:images].each do |image|
        @photo = current_user.photos.new(photo_params)
        @value = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image], :categorization => "google_tagging", :auto_tagging => 0.7)
        @photo.link = @value['secure_url']
        @photo.tag_list = @value['tags']
        @photo.save
      end
      redirect_to root_path
  end
```

The method returns one file and says
method `each' is undefined.

How can I pass an array of all the images I'm uploading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a form of array "[]" to images, like this(change it by your own logic):

```
<%= form_with(model: photo, remote: true, multipart: true) do |form| %>
    <% (1..5).each do %>
          <input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple>
    <% end %>

    <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Update:
Thanks to @SRack for pointing out that number index is not necessary, iamges[0], images[1] will work, but in fact, a form of params "images[]" is enough.

Comment: +1. N.B. you can actually do `name="images[]"` to return an array in the controller @leiliu, saving the need to add the index.